# Get html nodes that are not within a node with attribute X

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have the following xpath query, and I am not sure how to make it so it only finds items with the attribute `pi-repeat`, but not it's children that have that attribute.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@pi-repeat]') as $node) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Html example:

```
<body>
    <div pi-repeat="thing1">
        <div pi-repeat="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a-class">
        <div pi-repeat="thing2">
            <div pi-repeat="sub-item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see here there are four `pi-repeat` attributes, I would like my query to only select the ones that are not within an element `pi-repeat` attribute.

In this case, only `thing1` and `thing2` would get selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd predicate in the XPath below will do the job. It filters out elements where ancestor element has `pi-repeat` attribute :

```
//*[@pi-repeat][not(ancestor::*[@pi-repeat])]
```

Comment: You've read the "within" in the requirement as meaning "having an ancestor with...". It could also be read as "having a parent with..." in which case the answer would be `//*[@pi-repeat][not(..[@pi-repeat])]`.